# End of Sequence Error when using tf.estimator and tf.data

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` and `tf.data.Dataset` to feed data to the estimator:

Input Data function:

```
    def data_fn(data_dict, batch_size, mode, num_epochs=10):
        dataset = {}
        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_dict['train_data'].astype(np.float32))
            dataset = dataset.cache()
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size= batch_size * 10).repeat(num_epochs).batch(batch_size)
        else:
            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_dict['valid_data'].astype(np.float32))
            dataset = dataset.cache()
            dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

        iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
        next_element = iterator.get_next()

    return next_element
```

Train Function:

```
def train_model(data):
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
    config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,
                            log_device_placement=False)
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    run_config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(
        save_checkpoints_steps=10,
        keep_checkpoint_max=10,
        session_config=config
    )

    train_input = lambda: data_fn(data, 100, tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN, num_epochs=1)
    eval_input = lambda: data_fn(data, 1000, tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL)
    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, params=hps, config=run_config)
    train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(train_input, max_steps=100)
    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(eval_input,
                                      steps=None,
                                      throttle_secs = 30)

    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

The training goes fine, but when it comes to evaluation I get this error:

```
OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence
```

If I don't use `Dataset.batch` on evaluation dataset (by omitting the line `dataset[name] = dataset[name].batch(batch_size)` in `data_fn`) I get the same error but after a much longer time.

I can only avoid this error if I don't batch the data and use `steps=1` for evaluation, but does that perform the evaluation on the whole dataset?

I don't understand what causes this error as the documentation suggests I should be able to evaluate on batches too.

Note: I get the same error when using `tf.estimator.evaluate` on data batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question as a github issue and here is the response from the Tensorflow team:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19541

Copying from "xiejw" for completeness:

> If I understand correctly, this issue is "once give estimator an input_fn with dataset inside, the evaluate process will error out with OutOfRangeError."
>
> Estimator can handle this correctly actually. However, a known common root cause for this is metrics defined in model_fn have bug. We need to rule that part out first.
>
> @mrezak if possible, can you show the code about the model_fn? Or if you have a minimal reproducible script, that will be extremely helpful. -- Thanks in advance.
>
> A common problem for this is: metric in tensorflow should return two Ops: update_op and value_op. Estimator calls the update_op for each batch of the data in input source and, once it is exhausted, it call the value_op to get the metric values. The value_op here should have dependency back to variables reading only.
>
> Many model_fn puts the dependency of value_op with the input pipeline, so, estimator.evaluate will thereby trigger the input pipeline one more time, which errors out with OutOfRangeError

The problem was indeed how I defined the `eval_metric` in `model_fn`. In my actual code my total loss to be optimized was composed of multiple losses (reconstruction + L2 + KL) and in the evaluation part I wanted to get the reconstruction loss (on the validation data), which depended on the input data pipeline. My actual reconstruction cost was more complex than MSE (none of the other tf.metric functions as well) which was not straightforward to be implemented using tf.metric basic functions.

This is "xiejw"'s suggestion which fixed the issue:

```
my_total_loss =  ... # the loss you care. Pay attention to how you reduce the loss. 
eval_metric_ops = {'total_loss: tf.metrics.mean(my_total_loss)}
```